# Saving image in media folder via django admin issue

Tags: python, django

I want to store image by a form. And I want to store it in the media/student_img folder. But it not saving in the database neither into the folder.

models.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='student_img/', blank=False)
```

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   photo = request.FILES.get('photo')
   student=Student(photo=photo)
   student.save()
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

HTML template:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Photos of Student</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" 
     name="photo">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the default admin page to upload or a form in a template? Also when you try to upload does it save an object but just not upload the file?

Comment: I am not using forms.py, using an HTML template. Not it's not saving in the database either into the folder.

Comment: I updated the post. Have a look at views.py and the HTML template